# How to center Content in a Button Template and keep mouse events in empty area

Tags: c#, wpf, button, controltemplate, contentpresenter

I am using a `Button` `Template` to customize the look and feel of my buttons like so:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="6" BorderThickness="1">
        <ContentPresenter Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True" ContentSource="Content"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I want to center horizontally and vertically the `Content`, but when I do it the "empty" areas of the `Button` don't react to the `Mouse`. When I use `Stretch` the entire `Button` behaves alright, but the `Content` is aligned top-right.

How do I do both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make whole area of a `Border` hit test visible you need to initialise its `Background` property with some `Brush`. Can be even Transparent which will have same visual effect as default null.

```
 <Border ... Background="Transparent" />
```